# aiosmtpd localhost server doesn't respond

Tags: python, email, server, smtp

I'm trying to run an SMTP server that simply prints the incoming message from a sender.
Here is a server code:

```
import asyncio
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from smtplib import SMTP as Client
import time

class ExampleHandler:
    print('It works!')
    async def handle_RCPT(self, server, session, envelope, address, rcpt_options):
        if not address.endswith('@example.com'):
            return '550 not relaying to that domain'
        envelope.rcpt_tos.append(address)
        return '250 OK'

    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        print('Message from %s' % envelope.mail_from)
        print('Message for %s' % envelope.rcpt_tos)
        print('Message data:\n')
        for ln in envelope.content.decode('utf8', errors='replace').splitlines():
            print(f'> {ln}'.strip())
        print()
        print('End of message')
        return '250 Message accepted for delivery'
    controller = Controller(ExampleHandler())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = loop.create_server(controller, host='::1', port=8025)
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

And here is the code that send email:

```
from smtplib import SMTP as Client


host = "::1"
port = 8025
print(host, port)
client = Client(host, port)
print(client.getreply())

r = client.sendmail('a@example.com', ['b@example.com'], """\
From: Anne Person <anne@example.com>
To: Bart Person <bart@example.com>
Subject: A test
Message-ID: <ant>

Hi Bart, this is Anne.
""")
```

I'm running those scripts via two different terminals. In server case, I firstly active the venv it was made in and then run the script. In console the message "It works!" appears, presumably meaning that the server is launched. Then I run a script that sends message to the server without and in server terminal a following message appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Lev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py",
> line 80, in _run
> self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)   File "C:\Users\Lev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 847, in loop
> protocol = protocol_factory()
> TypeError: 'Controller' object is not callable

What might be the problem? Might there be issue with incorrect usage of asyncio?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved -- in loop.create_server instead of controller argument a controller.factory should be passed.